# Display date clicked as half hour interval

Tags: php, date

I'm looking for the following solution in PHP.

Whenever a user clicks on a page I want to store the time they clicked as an half hour interval in 12 hour AM/PM format.

For example a user clicks at:
7:23AM will be stored as 7:00AM-7:30AM, 9:44PM will be stored as 9:30PM-10:00PM, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump( date('H:i') );
$prev = time() - (time() % 1800);
$next = $prev + 1800;
var_dump( date('H:i A', $prev), date('H:i A', $next) );
```

as seen here: [How to round unix timestamp up and down to nearest half hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639642/how-to-round-unix-timestamp-up-and-down-to-nearest-half-hour)