# PHP Round time to hour

Tags: php, time, rounding

I'm trying to round my time to nearest hour, but every time I fail.

Is it possible to round time, but not change the structure? I tried to use ceil and floor, but I failed...

```
$date = "2015/04/20 06:59"; 
$date = date("Y/m/d H:0",strtotime($date));
print $date; //Need to print 2015/04/20 07:00
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639642/how-to-round-unix-timestamp-up-and-down-to-nearest-half-hour

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about rounding but you could do something like this:

```
$hour = date('H');
$minutes = date('i');

if ($minutes >= 30) 
{
    $hour++;
}
```

Oh, use modulo: [How to round unix timestamp up and down to nearest half hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639642/how-to-round-unix-timestamp-up-and-down-to-nearest-half-hour) (cheers @JoeCoder)